# CPU Type and CPU Utilization metric for stackdriver monitoring

Tags: google-cloud-stackdriver

I want to show custom metrics like CPU Type and CPU Utilization in stack driver monitoring.For this i am looking any monitoring api is available or not. 
Please let me know any suggestions on this.

Comment: This feels a little vague.  CPU utilization should indeed be a metric that is captured by default.  What kind of resource are you wishing to measure?  I'm assuming it is a Compute Engine instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a product from the GCP Marketplace if you are looking for these metrics from a non GCP resource, [BindPlane](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/bluemedora/bindplane).  Like AWS, or on premise server or VM.

They have a source collector that is for Host info that collects info on things like CPU utilization, cpu temp, cpu voltage, disk, memory, network performance, process info, free space on a file store, etc.

Here's the docs, looks like it's in Alpha: https://docs.bindplane.bluemedora.com/docs/host